# Let anonymous user download pdf off his own webform submission

Tags: webforms, 8

I have configured entity_print with webform for D8 and can download a submission as pdf from the submission view.
Now I tried to let anonymous users fill out a form and added a link to the pdf on the confirmation page. I checked the show own submissions for guests on the permission page of that webform.
But when I try to access the pdf with the submited data I get a permission denied message.
http://mywebsite/print/pdf/webform_submission/15?view_mode=html seems not to do the trick.

The use case just is: Display a confirmation page with the submitted values to the user and let the user download it as pdf.
Any hints on that?

Meanwhile I found this Thread: https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print/issues/2896424
Which says adding
`{{ content[0]['#webform_submission'].data.FIELD_NAME }}`
too the template should work. While Fieldname should be the name of the entityPdf/Attachment field.
But adding it to my webform-confirmation.htmltwig template does not return anything.

This too points in the same direction: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3198932
This seems to be a solution. After Doing the following:

1. Add permissions for anonymous users - "Webform submission: Use all print engines"
2. Enable "Allow users to view a submission using a secure token"
3. Add Link to submission with token [webform_submission:token-view-url]
4. Submit Webform as anonymous and click on link -> Download PDF

Maybe there is still a even more neat solution...

Okay meanwhile - the so called secure token isn't expiring so it es more like a everyone how knows the link not so secure token :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay after playing around with several options, best way in my eyes is:

- install entity print and wktmltopdf
- give guest users access to their own submissions (/admin/people/permissions)
- give guest users access to use any print engine (/admin/people/permissions)
- add a confirmation message like "Thank you for contacting us, you can download your submited data here  (at /admin/webform/manage/kontakt/settings/confirmation)
- The href to the PDF looks like this:   /print/pdf/webform_submission/[webform_submission:sid]

The access to the data will no longer be posibble after session timeout.
So there shouldnt be a concern with data security.

The Secure token method mentioned above would fail in cases where data security plays a role, as the token never times out and could easily be obtained from browser istory.